# Jquery Ajax Fails... randomly succeeds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my problem:
I try to make an Ajax call with JQuery,
this calls a PHP page, the code gets executed, and echoes OK if alright, STOP if not.
I don't get any text back (first problem),
and the real problem is that:
SOMETIMES the query succeeds, but ALWAYS returns an error. (even if my sql query in php page gets executed)

Here is the code :

```
<script>
$("a.confirm").click(function(event){
    var id = event.target.id;
    $.ajax({
        type    :"POST",
        url     :'./PHP/UTILS/confirm.php',
        data    :{  "id" : id,
                 },
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert("in progress");
        },
        complete: function(){
            alert("done");
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err + "\n");
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is for the ajax, now the page it calls :

```
<?php
include "./functionsExt.php";
$db = connectToDb('mydb');
$id = $_POST['id'];
$mysql = $db->prepare("UPDATE `test` SET `test_date_p` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `test_status` = '2' WHERE `test_id` = '$id'");
if($mysql->execute()){
    echo "OK";
}else{
    echo "STOP";
}
?>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: functionsExt.php is in the same folder as confirm.php, right?

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is called `NOW()`. Therefore you get STOP in your answer. Since the request in itself succeeds `success` is called.

Comment: well, functionsExt.php IS in the same folder as confirm.php... i already checked this... :(

Comment: sometimes the MYSQL query gets executed... and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP works fine, it writes in DB the current TS... i can't get the "answer" back

Comment: i use FireBug, and profiler gives me that as an answer : 

 Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error", plus...}

Details: error
Error: (nothing!)   


BUT the mysql query WORKED FINE (this time... sometimes it does not work... idk why^^)     now i tried again and the mysql query did not work... :/

Comment: still not working... anyone? any idea?

Comment: `url     :'./PHP/UTILS/confirm.php',` try your full url first. like `http://domain.com/PHP/UTILS/confirm.php`

Comment: it does not seem to solve the problem... but thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you prepare a query, and you put the variable straight into, it's the same as non-prepared. Don't lie to yourself. Use real prepared statements :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would like to suggest that you should try it after removing the comma in data after 'id'.

And i please do mention the following :

1. echo the post variable and check the response.
2. then echo that you want and check whether it is coming or not in response
3. a better way to write the success and failure

   ```
   success:   function(data)
   {    
   alert(data);
   }
   failure : function(){
   alert(failed);
   }
   ```

It will eventually alert you with the data that you are receiving in response. So it is good for testing purpose.

hope it helps:)

Comment: thanks for your reply... i removed the comma in data... i edited the success like you did... but it does not seem to go through the success part... nothing is displayed... i get the "complete alert" and the console log (so it's "error" again... ) :(   the interesting thing in this, is that SOMETIMES (idk when or why) the mysql query gets executed! now i edited the code as you shown, i tried and didnt work, but i'm sure that if i try a few more times, it will work once (but giving me an error log anyway!)... and then not work again for a while... :'(

Comment: have you tried echoing the post variable. are you getting the variable in your php file?

Comment: just write success and failure and comment the result :)

Comment: @user3774191 mark my answer as accepted then .:D  Then I would be happy to provide you some more ideas about your queries :P

Answer (score 0):

i think i found something interesting...
i tried echoing the post...
The post is well sent to the php file,

But i noticed that :

if i add event.preventDefault(); in my jquery code, i have the post echo + the "ok" displayed in an alert (guess it's the success alert cuz i don't have the log message this time...)

i will try again... (if it works like this, i need then to find a way to re-enable default link click function, i need to refresh the page... the page content is not the same after calling the ajax...)

tried again, and it seems to work now...
but, i don't close the topic, cause i have to add few more queries in my php file now... and i still need a way to refresh the page after execution... any idea?

(thanx stacky, you advice seems to have solved the "main" problem :P )